# Node.js mssql return recordset

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to learning Node.js, so I'm still getting used to asynchronous programming and callbacks.  I'm trying to query a MS SQL Server database and return the recordset to display in my view.

The mssql query is working correctly when printed to console.log.  My problem is not knowing how to properly return the data.

Here is my mssql query:

```
    var config = require('../../db/config');

async function getJobList(activeJD) {
    const sql = require('mssql')
    let sqlResult = '';
    try {
        await sql.connect(config)
        const result = await sql.query(`select top 10 [jobid], [title] from OrgJobs where ActiveJD = ${activeJD}`);

        console.log(result); // working correctly
        sqlResult = result;
    } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks
    }

    return sqlResult;
}

module.exports = getJobList;
```

Using express, I'm trying to have my route call this sql query and pass it's result to my view.  Here is my route code:

```
const express = require('express');
//....
const app = express();
//....
app.get('/jds', (req, res) => {
    const getJobList = require("../models/jds/list");

    let jobList = getJobList(0);

    res.render('jds/index', {
        title: appName + ' | Job Descriptions',
        header: 'Active Job Descriptions',
        data: jobList
    });

})
```

The recordset from getJobList() isn't being returned to jobList.  I've read around and I believe this is because getJobList is asynchronous and jobList is being called before getJobList has returned it's value, right?  If so, I believe I need to add a callback, but I'm not sure how to implement that into what I already have.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` method will always return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). That means that `jobList` is a *Promise*.

```
let jobList = getJobList(0);
```

You can either use the `await` syntax to "unpack" and get `sqlResult` from the promise (you would need to make your callback method `async` to do this), or simply use `.then` to get the return value from your promise (ie: `sqlResult`):

```
app.get('/jds', (req, res) => {
    const getJobList = require("../models/jds/list");

    const jobList = getJobList(0); // jobList is a promise
    jobList.then(result => { // result is sqlResult
      res.render('jds/index', {
        title: appName + ' | Job Descriptions',
        header: 'Active Job Descriptions',
        data: result
      });
    });  
})
```

Comment: This is a great answer. But, how can we include 2 queries inside 1 app.get route?

Comment: inside the `.get` run `sql.query` twice so you run each query. Use the callback it provides to get the data for each query

Comment: Nick please please provide an example ... I'm not sure that I understand what you said.

Comment: @JorgeLopez something like this https://jsfiddle.net/wzgyvcpd/

Comment: I'm simply speechless. Thank you. Sincerely.

Comment: Nick, I have just one more question. My query looks like this :
https://jsfiddle.net/jorgelopez141/xyq27ogL/
And my query takes a long time to run, hence my website takes a long time to run, how would you modify it so that the website does not wait for the query to run?

Comment: @JorgeLopez I'm not too sure what the best thing to do is in this case. One thing you can ask yourself is whether you really do need _all_ the data from your query at once. For example, if you need the data from the query to display in some sort of list, you can have "pages", and on each page you would display a section of the list (which you could obtain using the SQL LIMIT clause)

Comment: another option would be to use two HTML files and ajax. One which is your index.html page, which just contains your general website (eg: nav bar, footer, etc). Then, you can create another HTML file, which contains the content you want to load (ie: a list/table of data) based on your query. When the user goes to "/", you can serve them  your index.html file (without running ur SQL statement). Then, you can use jQuery / ajax to make a request to another endpoint, which will return the rendered HTML of your list/data. You can then use jQuery/JS to inject the HTML returned into your webpage

Comment: thankful for your comment. Your second option is to route to say '/queryOfTable' so that the user can load the query in a different route - that's actually a good idea. But, I have seen websites that load and put a loading spinner while something else loads - like a large media file (say youtube, for ex), or a SQL query.

Comment: @JorgeLopez yeah, with the second option you could use a loading spinner as the default content for your table. Then send a request for the HTML/rendered content to the `/queryOfTable` endpoint using ajax / jQuery. Once that loads, replace the loading spinner with the actual content you received